# Dismiss keyboard on tapping textfield

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a textfield which can be edited. Below this textfield, I have another textfield on the tap of which I go to another screen.

When I tap the 1st textfield, the keyboard comes up. But when I tap on the 2nd textfield the keyboard still remains (maybe because it is also a textfield). But I want the keyboard to dismiss the moment I tap the second textfield.

I'm using `IQKeyboardManager`.

This is what I have..But it's not working...

```
@IBAction func secondTextfield_Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UITextField).resignFirstResponder()
         
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set the delegate to the second textfield and implement the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`  delegate method.

```
secondTextField.delegate = self
```

In the following delegate method you can check the textfield and return true/false based on your textfield.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

   view.endEditing(true) //with will end editing for the view
   if textField == secondTextField {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

By returning false for the secondTextField the keyboard will not be opened for the second text field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you using textfield to go to anther page?
why don't you just use button instead
Second thing, if you want you can do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     ...
     secondTF.delegate = self
     ...
}
```

And call this function anywhere in your code:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   view.endEditing(true) 
   if textField == secondTF {
        // Navigate to the second VC with using storyBoard or navigationController
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```